# iOS 8 Universal storyboard for different View Controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, universal-storyboard

I'm using universal storyboard for iPhone and iPad sizes. But I need to make a push segue to `UITableViewConroller` in iPhone and `UICollectionViewController` in iPad. I know, I can make segue to different controllers after this code

`if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)`

But it's not so good I think, isn't it? Is there any way to do it exactly in storyboard?

Comment: You can use 1 storyboard for iPhone and 1 other storyboard for iPad

Comment: I know that there are a lot of solutions, but maybe someone knows the direct answer to my question